# How to bind multiple primitive values from JSON body in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

An old big ASP.NET MVC 5 legacy application uses the following way to bind multiple primitive values from a JSON body.

Example JSON body:

```
{
    "text": "foo",
    "value": 42
}
```

Example action:

```
public class FooController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync(string text, int value)
  {
      // ...
  }
}
```

How does one achieve the same in ASP.NET Core when the controller inherits from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`, with minimal changes to the existing code?

Comment: You can use [FromBody] but since you can only have one [FromBody] it force you to create a model that will aggregate your parameters, so probably it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, in my opinion - create a class/model to deserialize the request body into:

```cs
public class TextValuePair
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then ([noting that GET request bodies are supposed to have no semantic meaning...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/6621862)), your action signature as follows:

```cs
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> RenameMeAsync([FromBody] TextValuePair tvp)
  {
      // ...
  }
```